# Easier way to display text in python3

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5

I've been trying past 12h display text in python 3 with tkinter, seemed easy but this is what I've come up with. (Just recently started with python) But there has to be an easier way to display a window and some text inside of it?

```
    from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master

        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("GUI")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, command=self.showTxt())


    def showTxt(self):
        text = Label(self, text='Hello world...')
        text.pack()


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
app = Window(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What part about this is "not easy"?

Comment: You can condense all of this down to just four or five lines, but the version you've shown is closer to how you use tkinter in the real world (ie: outside of a tutorial or simple example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
T = Text(root, height=2, width=30)
T.pack()
T.insert(END, "Just a text Widget\nin two lines\n")
mainloop()
```